# How to setup a mocked WP_Query in a WP_UnitTestCase

Tags: php, wordpress, phpunit

How do I setup a mock global `$wp_query` for a unit test?

I basically want to setup the query so that [`is_single`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) returns true.

Stubbing over the function with namespaces is not an option since it clobbers the function for all remaining tests.

Comment: Unit test, wordpress? Mind blown

Comment: It is possible - just kind of painful. https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/automated-testing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WP_UnitTestCase::go_to($url)` sets a mocked request (WP_Query) for a url.